# Fragments exception on multiple rotations

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have an application that has a Dashboard with 1 or 2 pages (according to the user profile).

When the application starts the first time it shows only 3 buttons, and as the information arrives it can add up to more 3 buttons (in a total of 6). Those buttons have a specific order, that should be mantained:

- Button 1 is mandatory and should be first;
- Button 2 is mandatory and should be second;
- Button 6 is mandatory and should be the last (either when there are 3,4,5 or 6)
- Buttons 3 to 5 are not mandatory but should appear by the order of their number.

To have this effect I have several placeholders where the fragments are added. Whenever a new button arrives (Button 3 to 5) it enteres in the old place of the Button_6 which moves one place forward.

Because of the complex UI and behaviour, each button is a fragment.

The application can be in portrait and landscape, have 4 buttons in portrait, 3 in landscape. Whenever the application is rotated the activity calls the refreshDashboard method to redraw the UI.

Code:

```
public class DashboardBuilder
{
    private final static String TAG_BUTTON_1 = "BUTTON_1";
    private final static String TAG_BUTTON_2 = "BUTTON_2";
    private final static String TAG_BUTTON_3 = "BUTTON_3";
    private final static String TAG_BUTTON_4 = "BUTTON_4";
    private final static String TAG_BUTTON_5 = "BUTTON_5";
    private final static String TAG_BUTTON_6 = "BUTTON_6";

    private int width = 0;
    private int height = 0;
    private int pages = 0;

    private int buttonsPerPage = 4;
    private int orientation = Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT;

    public final String TAG = getClass().getSimpleName();

    public DashboardBuilder(DashboardPaginationActivity dashboard)
    {      
            FragmentManager.enableDebugLogging(false);   
    }

    //This is called each time there is a rotation. 
    public void rebuildDashboard(DashboardPaginationActivity dashboard, int orientation)
    {
        switch (orientation)
        {
            case Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE:
            case Configuration.ORIENTATION_SQUARE:
                buttonsPerPage = 3;
                break;
            default:
                buttonsPerPage = 4;
                break;
        }

        this.width = dashboard.getWidth();
        this.height = dashboard.getHeight();

        // Orientation changed
        if (this.orientation != orientation)
        {
            this.orientation = orientation;
            pages = 0;
        }
        rebuildDashboard(dashboard);
    }

    private synchronized void rebuildDashboard(DashboardPaginationActivity dashboard)
    {
        final Application application = (Application) dashboard.getApplication();
        final ArrayList<FragmentReference> fragmentsReferences = application.getFragmentsReferences();

        if (fragmentsReferences.size() == 0)
        {
            try
            {
                final String[] tags = new String[] { TAG_BUTTON_1, TAG_BUTTON_2, TAG_BUTTON_3, TAG_BUTTON_4, TAG_BUTTON_5, TAG_BUTTON_6 };
                for (String tag : tags)
                {
                    Fragment fragment = dashboard.getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(tag);
                    if (fragment != null)
                    {
                        LOG.debug(LOG.TAG_ADAPTER, this, "rebuildDashboard : delete tag -> " + tag, null);
                        fragmentsReferences.add(new FragmentReference(tag, fragment.getId()));
                    }
                }

                final ViewGroup pages = (ViewGroup) dashboard.findViewById(R.id.dashboard_pages);
                pages.removeAllViews();

                final ViewGroup pagination = (ViewGroup) dashboard.findViewById(R.id.pagination);
                pagination.removeAllViews();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
            }

            // Definitely a first run
            if (fragmentsReferences.size() == 0)
            {
                // add mandatory buttons + refresh layout
                fragmentsReferences.add(new FragmentReference(TAG_BUTTON_1, -1));
                fragmentsReferences.add(new FragmentReference(TAG_BUTTON_2, -1));
                fragmentsReferences.add(new FragmentReference(TAG_BUTTON_6, -1));
            }

            refreshDashboard(dashboard, false);
        }
        else
        {
            // refresh layout
            refreshDashboard(dashboard, true);
        }

    }

    public void refreshDashboard(DashboardPaginationActivity dashboard, boolean exitOnNewButton)
    {
        final Application application = (Application) dashboard.getApplication();
        final ArrayList<FragmentReference> fragmentsReferences = application.getFragmentsReferences();

        int buttonsCounter = fragmentsReferences.size();

        int pagesCounter = (buttonsCounter / (buttonsPerPage + 1)) + 1;
        for (int i = pages; i < pagesCounter; i++)
        {
            final View pageInflator = createPage(dashboard, i);
            if (pageInflator != null && i > 0)
            {
                swapIDs(i, pageInflator);
            }
        }

        final FragmentManager manager = dashboard.getSupportFragmentManager();
        final FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
        for (int i = fragmentsReferences.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            Fragment fragment = null;
            if (TAG_BUTTON_1.equalsIgnoreCase(fragmentsReferences.get(i).getTag()))
            {
                fragment = manager.findFragmentByTag(TAG_BUTTON_1);
                if (fragment != null)
                {
                    transaction.remove(fragment);
                }
                ButtonOneFragment button = new ButtonOneFragment();
                button.setRetainInstance(false);
                transaction.replace(getPlaceHolder(i), button, TAG_BUTTON_1);
                transaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);

                fragmentsReferences.get(i).setPlaceHolder(getPlaceHolder(i));
            }
            else if (TAG_BUTTON_2.equalsIgnoreCase(fragmentsReferences.get(i).getTag()))
            {
                fragment = manager.findFragmentByTag(TAG_BUTTON_2);
                if (fragment != null)
                {
                    transaction.remove(fragment);
                }
                ButtonTwoFragment button = new ButtonTwoFragment();
                button.setRetainInstance(false);
                transaction.replace(getPlaceHolder(i), button, TAG_BUTTON_2);
                transaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);

                fragmentsReferences.get(i).setPlaceHolder(getPlaceHolder(i));

            }
            else if (TAG_BUTTON_3.equalsIgnoreCase(fragmentsReferences.get(i).getTag()))
            {

                fragment = manager.findFragmentByTag(TAG_BUTTON_3);
                if (fragment != null)
                {
                    transaction.remove(fragment);
                }
                ButtonThreeFragment button = new ButtonThreeFragment();
                button.setRetainInstance(false);
                transaction.replace(getPlaceHolder(i), button, TAG_BUTTON_3);
                transaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
                fragmentsReferences.get(i).setPlaceHolder(getPlaceHolder(i));

            }
            else if (TAG_BUTTON_4.equalsIgnoreCase(fragmentsReferences.get(i).getTag()))
            {
                fragment = manager.findFragmentByTag(TAG_BUTTON_4);
                if (fragment != null)
                {
                    transaction.remove(fragment);
                }
                ButtonFourFragment button = new ButtonFourFragment();
                button.setRetainInstance(false);
                transaction.replace(getPlaceHolder(i), button, TAG_BUTTON_4);
                transaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
                fragmentsReferences.get(i).setPlaceHolder(getPlaceHolder(i));
            }
            else if (TAG_BUTTON_5.equalsIgnoreCase(fragmentsReferences.get(i).getTag()))
            {
                fragment = manager.findFragmentByTag(TAG_BUTTON_5);
                if (fragment != null)
                {
                    transaction.remove(fragment);
                }
                ButtonFiveFragment button = new ButtonFiveFragment();
                button.setRetainInstance(false);
                transaction.replace(getPlaceHolder(i), button, TAG_BUTTON_5);
                transaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
                fragmentsReferences.get(i).setPlaceHolder(getPlaceHolder(i));
            }
            else if (TAG_BUTTON_6.equalsIgnoreCase(fragmentsReferences.get(i).getTag()))
            {
                fragment = manager.findFragmentByTag(TAG_BUTTON_6);
                if (fragment != null)
                {
                    transaction.remove(fragment);
                }
                ButtonSixFragment button = new ButtonSixFragment();
                button.setRetainInstance(false);
                transaction.replace(getPlaceHolder(i), button, TAG_BUTTON_6);
                transaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
                fragmentsReferences.get(i).setPlaceHolder(getPlaceHolder(i));
            }

            if (exitOnNewButton)
            {
                // on first new button found
                if (fragmentsReferences.get(i).getPlaceHolder() < 0) break;
            }
        }

        buttonsCounter = fragmentsReferences.size();
        pagesCounter = (buttonsCounter / (buttonsPerPage + 1)) + 1;

        for (int i = pages; i > pagesCounter; i--)
        {
            // scroll to first if removing
            dashboard.changePage(0);
            removePage(dashboard, i - 1);
        }

        pages = pagesCounter;
        dashboard.setTotalScreens(pages);

        try
        {
            // we suspect that this is only required when a remove happens
            // keep it here in all cases to be on the safe site...
            transaction.commit();
            manager.executePendingTransactions();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            // ignore exception
            LOG.error(LOG.TAG_FRAGMENT, this, "refreshDashboard", e.getMessage());
            // e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private View createPage(DashboardPaginationActivity dashboard, int index)
    {
        final View pageHolder = dashboard.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.dashboard_page, null);
        pageHolder.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(getHorizontalScrollWidth(dashboard), getHorizontalScrollHeight(dashboard)));

        View existingView = null;

        final View page = pageHolder.findViewById(R.id.page);
        switch (index)
        {
            case 0:
                if (dashboard.findViewById(R.id.page1) == null)
                {
                    page.setId(R.id.page1);
                }
                existingView = dashboard.findViewById(R.id.page1);
                break;
            case 1:
                if (dashboard.findViewById(R.id.page2) == null)
                {
                    page.setId(R.id.page2);
                }
                existingView = dashboard.findViewById(R.id.page2);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        if (existingView != null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        // add page holder to dashboard

        ViewGroup pages = ((ViewGroup) dashboard.findViewById(R.id.dashboard_pages));
        pages.addView(pageHolder);

        return pageHolder;
    }

    private void removePage(DashboardPaginationActivity dashboard, int index)
    {
        if (((ViewGroup) dashboard.findViewById(R.id.dashboard_pages)).getChildCount() > index)
        {
            ((ViewGroup) dashboard.findViewById(R.id.dashboard_pages)).removeViewAt(index);
        }
    }

          private void swapIDs(int index, View pageInflator)
    {
        if (orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE || orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_SQUARE)
        {
            swapLandscapeIDs(index, pageInflator);
        }
        else
        {
            swapPortraitIDs(index, pageInflator);
        }
    }

    private Integer getFragmentPlaceHolder(DashboardPaginationActivity dashboard, String tag)
    {
        if (tag != null)
        {
            final Application application = (Application) dashboard.getApplication();
            final ArrayList<FragmentReference> fragmentsReferences = application.getFragmentsReferences();

            for (int i = 0; i < fragmentsReferences.size(); i++)
            {
                final String fragmentTag = fragmentsReferences.get(i).getTag();
                if (tag.equalsIgnoreCase(fragmentTag))
                {
                    return fragmentsReferences.get(i).getPlaceHolder();
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    private Integer addFragmentReference(DashboardPaginationActivity dashboard, String tag)
    {
        int index = 0;
        if (tag != null)
        {
            final Application application = (Application) dashboard.getApplication();
            final ArrayList<FragmentReference> fragmentsReferences = application.getFragmentsReferences();

            if (tag.equalsIgnoreCase(TAG_BUTTON_1))
            {
                fragmentsReferences.add(0, new FragmentReference(TAG_BUTTON_1, -1));
                index = 0;
            }

            if (tag.equalsIgnoreCase(TAG_BUTTON_2))
            {
                fragmentsReferences.add(1, new FragmentReference(TAG_BUTTON_2, -1));
                index = 1;
            }

            if (tag.equalsIgnoreCase(TAG_BUTTON_3))
            {
                fragmentsReferences.add(2, new FragmentReference(TAG_BUTTON_3, -1));
                index = 2;
            }
            else if (tag.equalsIgnoreCase(TAG_BUTTON_4))
            {
                if (TAG_BUTTON_3.equalsIgnoreCase(fragmentsReferences.get(2).getTag()))
                {
                    fragmentsReferences.add(3, new FragmentReference(TAG_BUTTON_4, -1));
                    index = 3;
                }
                else
                {
                    fragmentsReferences.add(2, new FragmentReference(TAG_BUTTON_4, -1));
                    index = 2;
                }
            }
            else if (tag.equalsIgnoreCase(TAG_BUTTON_5))
            {
                if (fragmentsReferences.size() == 5 && TAG_BUTTON_4.equalsIgnoreCase(fragmentsReferences.get(3).getTag()))
                {
                    fragmentsReferences.add(4, new FragmentReference(TAG_BUTTON_5, -1));
                    index = 4;
                }
                else if (fragmentsReferences.size() == 4 && (TAG_BUTTON_3.equalsIgnoreCase(fragmentsReferences.get(2).getTag()) || TAG_BUTTON_4.equalsIgnoreCase(fragmentsReferences.get(2).getTag())))
                {
                    fragmentsReferences.add(3, new FragmentReference(TAG_BUTTON_5, -1));
                    index = 3;
                }
                else
                {
                    fragmentsReferences.add(2, new FragmentReference(TAG_BUTTON_5, -1));
                    index = 2;
                }
            }
        }
        return index;
    }

    private void removeFragmentReference(DashboardPaginationActivity dashboard, String tag)
    {
        if (tag != null)
        {
            final Application application = (Application) dashboard.getApplication();
            final ArrayList<FragmentReference> fragmentsReferences = application.getFragmentsReferences();

            // start at 2 means that button 1 and 2 will never be removed
            for (int i = 0; i < fragmentsReferences.size(); i++)
            {
                final String fragmentTag = fragmentsReferences.get(i).getTag();
                if (tag.equalsIgnoreCase(fragmentTag))
                {
                    fragmentsReferences.remove(i);
                    break;
                }
            }

            final FragmentManager manager = dashboard.getSupportFragmentManager();
            final Fragment fragment = manager.findFragmentByTag(tag);
            if (fragment != null)
            {
                final FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();

                // remove store references and other resources
                // ((ButtonFragment) fragment).cleanup();

                transaction.remove(fragment);
                transaction.commit();

                try
                {
                    // we suspect that this is only required when a remove happens
                    // keep it here in all cases to be on the safe site...
                    manager.executePendingTransactions();
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    // ignore exception
                    LOG.debug(LOG.TAG_FRAGMENT, this, "removeFragmentReference", null);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public boolean buttonExists(DashboardPaginationActivity dashboard, String tag)
    {
        if (tag == null) return false;

        final Application application = (Application) dashboard.getApplication();
        final ArrayList<FragmentReference> fragmentsReferences = application.getFragmentsReferences();

        for (int i = 0; i < fragmentsReferences.size(); i++)
        {
            final String fragmentTag = fragmentsReferences.get(i).getTag();
            if (tag.equalsIgnoreCase(fragmentTag))
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    private int getPlaceHolder(int index)
    {
        switch (index)
        {
            case 0:
                return R.id.placeHolder01;
            case 1:
                return R.id.placeHolder02;
            case 2:
                return R.id.placeHolder03;
            case 3:
                return R.id.placeHolder04;
            case 4:
                return R.id.placeHolder05;
            case 5:
                return R.id.placeHolder06;
            case 6:
                return R.id.placeHolder07;
            case 7:
                return R.id.placeHolder08;
            case 8:
                return R.id.placeHolder09;
            case 9:
                return R.id.placeHolder10;
            case 10:
                return R.id.placeHolder11;
            case 11:
                return R.id.placeHolder12;
            default:
                return -1;
        }
    }

    private void swapPortraitIDs(int index, View pageInflated)
    {
        switch (index)
        {
            case 1:
                pageInflated.findViewById(R.id.placeHolder01).setId(R.id.placeHolder05);
                pageInflated.findViewById(R.id.placeHolder02).setId(R.id.placeHolder06);
                pageInflated.findViewById(R.id.placeHolder03).setId(R.id.placeHolder07);
                pageInflated.findViewById(R.id.placeHolder04).setId(R.id.placeHolder08);
                break;
            case 2:
                pageInflated.findViewById(R.id.placeHolder01).setId(R.id.placeHolder09);
                pageInflated.findViewById(R.id.placeHolder02).setId(R.id.placeHolder10);
                pageInflated.findViewById(R.id.placeHolder03).setId(R.id.placeHolder11);
                pageInflated.findViewById(R.id.placeHolder04).setId(R.id.placeHolder12);
                break;
            default:
                LOG.error(LOG.TAG_ACTIVITY, activity, "swapPortraitIDs", "Invalid page number: " + index);
                break;
        }

    }

    private void swapLandscapeIDs(int index, View pageInflated)
    {
        switch (index)
        {
            case 1:
                pageInflated.findViewById(R.id.placeHolder01).setId(R.id.placeHolder04);
                pageInflated.findViewById(R.id.placeHolder02).setId(R.id.placeHolder05);
                pageInflated.findViewById(R.id.placeHolder03).setId(R.id.placeHolder06);
                break;
            case 2:
                pageInflated.findViewById(R.id.placeHolder01).setId(R.id.placeHolder07);
                pageInflated.findViewById(R.id.placeHolder02).setId(R.id.placeHolder08);
                pageInflated.findViewById(R.id.placeHolder03).setId(R.id.placeHolder09);
                break;
            default:
                LOG.error(LOG.TAG_ACTIVITY, activity, "swapLandscapeIDs", "Invalid page number: " + index);
                break;
        }
    }


    public int[] getPagesIds(AbstractActivity activity)
    {
        switch (pages)
        {
            case 1:
                return new int[] { R.id.page1 };
            case 2:
                return new int[] { R.id.page1, R.id.page2 };
            default:
                LOG.error(LOG.TAG_ACTIVITY, activity, "getPagesIds", "Invalid page number: " + pages);
                return new int[0];
        }
    }

}
```

I had to embrace manager.executePendingTransactions(); with try catch because it would "randomly" throw java.lang.IllegalStateExceptio­n: Recursive entry to executePendingTransactions if a lot of rotations in a small ammount of time would occour.

I think that this is due to the asynchronous nature of the Fragments Manager.

I've "solved" the problem with those try catches..still I would like to know if there is a more correct way to solve it and/or advices.

**StackTrace before the Try catchs:**

```
19:04:47.402 E/AndroidRuntime( 1352): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 
 19:04:47.402 E/AndroidRuntime( 1352): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Recursive entry to executePendingTransactions 
 19:04:47.402 E/AndroidRuntime( 1352): at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1388) 
 19:04:47.402 E/AndroidRuntime( 1352): at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:420) 
 19:04:47.402 E/AndroidRuntime( 1352): at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587) 
 19:04:47.402 E/AndroidRuntime( 1352): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92) 
 19:04:47.402 E/AndroidRuntime( 1352): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123) 
 19:04:47.402 E/AndroidRuntime( 1352): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683) 
 19:04:47.402 E/AndroidRuntime( 1352): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
 19:04:47.402 E/AndroidRuntime( 1352): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507) 
 19:04:47.402 E/AndroidRuntime( 1352): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839) 
 19:04:47.402 E/AndroidRuntime( 1352): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597) 
 19:04:47.402 E/AndroidRuntime( 1352): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
 19:04:47.406 W/ActivityManager(  107):   Force finishing activity com.dashboard.tests/.activity.MainActivity
 19:04:47.402 E/AndroidRuntime( 1352): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 
 19:04:47.402 E/AndroidRuntime( 1352): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Recursive entry to executePendingTransactions 
 19:04:47.402 E/AndroidRuntime( 1352): at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1388) 
 19:04:47.402 E/AndroidRuntime( 1352): at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:420)
```

As requested on Android Developer Office Hours (http://www.google.com/moderator/#15/e=1ac28e&t=1ac28e.51), here is the code so the Android Crew can look at it.

Thanks

Ps: Sorry for the long snippet of code.

Comment: It would be nice if you could add the stack trace to your post.

Comment: Hi, did you get any fix for this?

Comment: The problem I think was that the layout was to complex for the GC to collect during the consecutive rotations with the main thread always being used. 

The stupid but true solution is to make the layout less complex. 

If you don't have that option and you have this problem.. you're in for trouble.